# Pandas: Dealing with Boolean in Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Having a real mind blank right now.

I have a DataFrame in the format `[userid],[q1],[q2],[q3],[q4]` (Each q. column is dtype boolean).

```
   q1    q2     q3    q4     userid
0  True  False  True  False  1
1  True  True   False False  2
2  False False  True  True   3
3  True  True   True  True   4
4  False False  True  True   5
5  True  True   False False  6
```

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to pivot or groupby the values without having to do this individually for each column.

`df['q1'].value_counts()` will return values as expected:

```
False    7138
True     2768
dtype: int64
```

I'd like to get to this, and I can't quite get there:

```
        q1    q2    q3
True    600   45    700
False   245   800   145
```

Not sure if I need to convert the boolean to int, or if I am missing a transform or a map step.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can just call `apply` and pass `value_counts`:

```
In [13]:
df.ix[:,:'q3'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)

Out[13]:
       q1  q2  q3
True    4   3   4
False   2   3   2
```

As @DSM has pointed out if you have columns with all `True`/`False` then it will insert `NaN` for the non-existing values in which case you can call `fillna(0)` like so:

```
df.ix[:,:'q3'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

Comment: `.loc` > `.ix`?  And in principle we might need a `.fillna(0)` if a column doesn't contain both True and False.

Comment: You could also select the `q` columns with: `df.filter(regex='^q')`. (This will work regardless of the order of the columns.)

Comment: @DSM no diff here, I tend to use `.ix` when slicing cols personally

Comment: @unutbu the OP showed cols up to `q3` which is what I did wouldn't your code snippet return `q4` too?

Comment: @EdChum: Indeed, I missed that. Of course, the OP could use `df.filter(regex='^q[123]')` in that case...

Comment: @unutbu yes that'd work but it depends on how complex/simple the OP's real requirements are

Comment: @DSM that's true (regarding `fillna`) my assumption was that since the dtype was all `boolean` that all rows were filled

Comment: Even if all columns are *filled*, if a column is all True then alignment will put a NaN for index=False.